# Laravel Google Compute Engine - Queued jobs not working

Tags: laravel, google-compute-engine, laravel-queue

Thank you in advance,

I have created jobs and queued them well using the link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues
it is working well in local and over `AWS` too but not in google compute engine
when I execute the `php artisan queue:work` will start running queued jobs but not working over the google compute engine

I used the below config in `.env`

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```